# Find the right motor to lift a robot's arm

Tags: dc-motor, robotics

I'm trying to find the right DC motor to lift a robot's arm.
I know the total weight of the arm, its length, and its center of mass.
The motor only needs to lift the arm up about 45deg.
How exactly I calculate and find a proper motor for these requirements.
Is there more data that I need?

Comment: How accurate do you need the arm to be? If you need it to have sub-mm accuracy, and relatively strong (can pick up a few kg), then a typical 3" NEMA stepper would be required. If accuracy isn't required, a small an simple gearmotor is all that's needed. This might be a better question for one of the more mechanical stackexhanges, as this isn't that much of a electronics question per se.

Comment: At the moment, it doesn't have to be much accurate.

Comment: Are you going to direct-drive the arm? Or will there be a belt or chain or gear?

Comment: It will be direct drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I am an EE, not a mech engineer, so take everything I say with a grain of salt.

Torque is a mass times a distance. Motors are typically rated in oz-in, or kg/cm. If I have a motor rated for 16 kg/cm, this means that I can have a 1kg load at the end of a 16cm massless rod. Obviously there are no massless rods (thanks for nothing, Higgs Boson). If we take the distance from thr center of mass with load attached to the "gripper" or whatever to where the motor is placed, and multiply that by the mass of the whole thang, you should get the rating of motor that you need.

Now that you have that, you need to figure out what type of motor you need. A typical [spur gear motor](http://www.robotshop.com/en/ghm-13-spur-gear-head-motor.html) has low accuracy, but relatively high torque for the size. It's also really easy to drive these. The robotic arms I've had have all had spur gearmotors. The one shown has 16.7 kg/cm of torque.

A stepper motor ([say, this one](http://www.robotshop.com/en/rbsoy03-soyo-unipolar-stepper-motor.html)) is really, mind-bogglingly accurate. They're also pretty torquey. However, they'll be a bit harder to drive.

Comment: "A stepper motor (say, this one) is really, mind-bogglingly accurate." Pfff. I've worked on a system with accuracies on the order of 2 seconds of arc.

Comment: @whatroughbeast ["WhatRoughBeast's motor is accurate. You just won't belive how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly precise it is. I mean, DC177E might think his NEMA motor is pretty accurate, but that's just peanuts to 2 arcseconds. Listen..."](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/33085.html)

Comment: Hmmpf. Kids these days. You try to tell them what precise is, but will they listen? Noo. It's all, 1.8 degrees this, 0.9 degrees that.